# How to list twice the same GET method in Swagger integrated in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a `@RestController` with a `GET` method to list all the instances of a Resource `R`

I want `swagger-ui` to list thrice this `GET` method like this:

- findRByFoo
- findRByBar
- findRByFooAndBar

that corresponds to the following `GET` petitions:

- `/resources?foo=myFoo`
- `/resources?bar=myBar`
- `/resources?foo=myFoo&bar=myBar`

so that the clients of my API Rest don't have to guess that they can search by `foo` or `bar` and can simply look at the `swagger-ui` (version `2.9.2`)  and use those API calls

However, given that the three methods are at the `/resources` path, swagger simply lists one of them and only one.

The question is, **How may I list the three API calls?**

*Edit*: It seems to be a limitation of Swagger 2 [Unable to add multiple operations on same path in swagger rest API documentation #1378](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1378), so let me rephrase the question as:

- **How may I circumvent this limitation?**
- **Does it mean that the design of my API Rest is not as *Rest* as should be?**

Comment: Are the `foo` and `bar` params mandatory? Ie. Will `/resources` work without these params?

Comment: In OpenAPI/Swagger terms, an operation as a combination of an HTTP method + path (w/o query params), so your scenario is not supported. You might need to split your method into several methods like `/resources/findByFoo?foo=...` and `/resources/findByBar?bar=...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrited the `RController` to have a single `GET`

```
@RestController("/path-to-r")
public class RController
{
    @GetMapping
    public List<R> findR(Optional<String> foo, Optional<String> bar)
    {
     ....
    }

}
```

And added `genericModelSubstitutes` as explained in [Java 8 Optional @RequestParam lost from the swagger-ui #1848](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1848#issuecomment-304825925)

The final result is such that when the clients of my API click in the combo they can see the two optional parameters to include in the `GET` petition

[image]